# What does $x=w_0(1)$ mean?

Tags: notation, exponential-function

Given as the solution to $e^x=\frac{1}{x}$ on [symbolab.com](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/equation-calculator/e%5E%7Bx%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lambert-W function is define as the inverse function of $x\mapsto xe^x$ and your equation is equivalent to $xe^x=1$.